# For-in loop in Dart

Tags: dart

When I use for-in loop in Dart, which one should I use, and why?

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

- `for (var number in numbers)`
- `for (final number in numbers)`
- `for (int number in numbers)`
- `for (final int number in numbers)`
- Or else?

Answer (score 2):

From the above options, all of them would work. But the cleaner way is to use

```
for(var number in numbers)
```

**Why?**

The `var` we declare is the data type which accepts every types, and become free of getting the `DataType mismatch compile time error`. It gives you more freedom on working with the variables of the `List`.

However, the other ones are more stringent towards a particular data type, in this case `int`.

I have followed some of the documentations, and there, `var` is the preferred way of using the `for...in loop`. Please see => [dart for-in-loop](https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-for-in-loop)

**Add-ons**

There is one more looping style in dart, and that is [forEach()](https://www.tutorialkart.com/dart/dart-list-iterate-over-elements/).
**Please note:**

> Note that this guideline specifically says **“function literal”**. If you want to invoke some already existing function on each element, `forEach()` is fine.

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

numbers.forEach((element){
   print(element); // 1 2 3 4
});

// OR - thanks to Richard
numbers.forEach(print); // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `forEach` comes over from JavaScript, and is not considered idiomatic Dart except in cases where brevity would improve the readability; but in that case, your code should be: `numbers.forEach(print);`

Comment: That's a better way @RichardAmbler . I use it very commonly hence it was in my mind `numbers.forEach((element){})`. Your suggestion is indeed good. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Effective Dart: Usage](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal) page, `var number in numbers` or `final number in numbers` is the most idiomatic way to iterate through items in a list.

In general, we should avoid the `forEach` method and allow Dart to infer the type where stating the type would be redundant to us, the editor and the software.